# Make a list with non-decreasing order elements of a list in Python

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop

I have a list `a = [2,2,1,3,4,1]` .
I want to make a new list c with the non-decreasing elements lists of list a.
That means my expected form is -

```
c = [[2,2],[1,3,4],[1]]
```

Here is my code:

```
>>> c = []
>>> for x in a:
...     xx = a[0]
...     if xx > x:
...             b = a[:x]
...             c.append(b)
...             a = a[x:]
```

but my output is:

```
>>> c
[[2], [2]]
```

How can i make a list with all non-decreasing part of list a?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initialise the first entry of `c` with `[a[0]]` and then either append the current value from `a` to the end of the current list in `c` if it is >= the previous value, otherwise append a new list containing that value to `c`:

```
a = [2,2,1,3,4,1]
c = [[a[0]]]
last = a[0]
for x in a[1:]:
    if x >= last:
        c[-1].append(x)
    else:
        c.append([x])
    last = x

print(c)
```

Output:

```
[[2, 2], [1, 3, 4], [1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are after correctly then what you want is to split the list every time the number decreases.  If so then this should do what you need

```
c = []
previous_element = a[0]
sub_list = [previous_element]
for element in a[1:]:
    if previous_element > element:
        c.append(sub_list)
        sub_list = []
    previous_element = element
    sub_list.append(previous_element)
c.append(sub_list)
```

Output:

> In [1]: c
>
> Out[2]: [[2, 2], [1, 3, 4], [1]]

There is possibly a clearer way to right the above, but it's pre coffee for me ;)

Also note that this code assumes that `a` will contain at least one item, if that is not always the case then you will need to either add an if statement around this, or re-structure the loop in a more while loop